# chrome user agent doesn't work for a scrapper

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, urllib, user-agent

I have the following code to scrape images:

```
import os, requests, lxml, re, json, urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from os.path import expanduser

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

params = {
    "q": "mincraft wallpaper 4k",  # search query
    "tbm": "isch",  # image results
    "hl": "en",  # language of the search
    "gl": "us",  # country where search comes from
    "ijn": "0"  # page number
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

def get_original_images():
    google_images = []
    all_script_tags = soup.select("script")
    matched_images_data = "".join(re.findall(r"AF_initDataCallback\(([^<]+)\);", str(all_script_tags)))
    matched_images_data_fix = json.dumps(matched_images_data)
    matched_images_data_json = json.loads(matched_images_data_fix)
    matched_google_image_data = re.findall(r'\"b-GRID_STATE0\"(.*)sideChannel:\s?{}}', matched_images_data_json)
    matched_google_images_thumbnails = ", ".join(
        re.findall(r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]',
                   str(matched_google_image_data))).split(", ")
    thumbnails = [
        bytes(bytes(thumbnail, "ascii").decode("unicode-escape"), "ascii").decode("unicode-escape") for thumbnail in
        matched_google_images_thumbnails
    ]
    # removing previously matched thumbnails for easier full resolution image matches.
    removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails = re.sub(
        r'\[\"(https\:\/\/encrypted-tbn0\.gstatic\.com\/images\?.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]', "", str(matched_google_image_data))

    matched_google_full_resolution_images = re.findall(r"(?:'|,),\[\"(https:|http.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]",
                                                       removed_matched_google_images_thumbnails)
    full_res_images = [
        bytes(bytes(img, "ascii").decode("unicode-escape"), "ascii").decode("unicode-escape") for img in
        matched_google_full_resolution_images
    ]
    for index, (metadata, thumbnail, original) in enumerate(
            zip(soup.select('.isv-r.PNCib.MSM1fd.BUooTd'), thumbnails, full_res_images), start=1):
        google_images.append({
            "title": metadata.select_one(".VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb")["title"],
            "link": metadata.select_one(".VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb")["href"],
            "source": metadata.select_one(".fxgdke").text,
            "thumbnail": thumbnail,
            "original": original
        })
        # Download original images
        print(f'Downloading {index} image...')
        opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
        opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent',
                              'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36')]
        urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

        urllib.request.urlretrieve(original, f'/Scrape/original_size_img_{index}.jpg')

    return google_images
print(get_original_images())
```

And I get no image. I feel the problem is with the user agent I provided.

I tried different user agents, and none could work. I tried one from here https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent/ as well, but it didn't work. What is the issue here?

Comment: Are you using a trash scrapper or did you mean scraper?

Comment: It depends on your definition, if you find the above code a trash scrapper, then let it be, and propose a real scraper please

Comment: My goal is to have high resolution images.